# bcdedit error: "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: windows, debugging, bcdedit

I'm trying to set up for kernel debugging, so I'm using the command:

```
bcdedit /set debug on
```

Unfortunately, I get the response

```
The parameter is incorrect.
```

a) does anyone know how to debug that error?

b) if not, can someone point me to an article on rebuilding the database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the GUID argument, as explained in this bit copied directly from [BCDEdit Command-Line Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdedit-command-line-options):

... use the following syntax to enable kernel or boot debug.

```
bcdedit /set <id> debug on
```

-or-

```
bcdedit /set <id> bootdebug on
```

where  is the GUID of the Loader object that is used to load the operating system. "Default" can be used if the operating system is the default option of the Boot Manager menu.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with the `/store U:\windows\Boot\DVD\EFI\BCD` paramater ? or does it only work on currently running?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.